# Pandas pivot table: Aggregate function by count of a particular string

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pivot-table, aggregate-functions

I am trying to analyse a DataFrame which contains the Date as the index, and Name and Message as columns.

df.head() returns:

```
            Name           Message
Date        
2020-01-01  Tom ‎           image omitted
2020-01-01  Michael        ‎image omitted
2020-01-02  James          ‎image Happy new year you wonderfully awfully people...
2020-01-02  James          I was waiting for you ‎image
2020-01-02  James          QB whisperer ‎image
```

This is the pivot table I was trying to call off the initial df, which the aggfunc being the count of the existence of a word (eg. image)

```
df_s = df.pivot_table(values='Message',index='Date',columns='Name',aggfunc=(lambda x: x.value_counts()['image']))
```

Which ideally would show, as an **example**:

```
 Name        Tom    Michael   James
 Date                                   
 2020-01-01    1       1        0
 2020-01-02    0       0        3
```

For instance, I've done another df.pivot_table using

```
df_m = df.pivot_table(values='Message',index='Date',columns='Name',aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()))
```

Which aggregates based off the number of messages in a day and this returns the table fine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for the fun of it, and an alternative to the same answer. It is just a play on the different options Pandas provides :

```
      #or df1.groupby(['Date','Name']) if the index has a name
res = (df1.groupby([df1.index,df1.Name])
          .Message.agg(','.join)
          .str.count('image')
          .unstack(fill_value=0)
      )

res

Name      James   Michael   Tom ‎
Date            
2020-01-01  0       1        1
2020-01-02  3      0         0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) for number of matched values to new column added to DataFrame by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and then pivoting with `sum`:

```
df_m = (df.reset_index()
          .assign(count= df['Message'].str.count('image'))
          .pivot_table(index='Date', 
                       columns='Name', 
                       values='count' ,
                       aggfunc='sum', 
                       fill_value=0))
print (df_m)
Name        James  Michael  Tom
Date                           
2020-01-01      0        1    1
2020-01-02      3        0    0
```

Comment: if u dont mind, where is the 2020-01-02 in the orginal df? cant seem to locate it

Comment: @sammywemmy - You are right, so edited sample in question for match.